# Android Profile GPU rendering: Large Execute time (red bars) while scrolling

Tags: android, performance, android-scrollview, android-cardview

The screen consists of a scrollview, which has a linearlayout with 4-5 CardViews laid out vertically. Each CardView has nested views inside of it.

On lower end devices, the scrolling is not at all smooth (lot of "jank"). Profile GPU rendering shows that the 16 ms mark is being missed almost on every frame, due to very large red bars, indicating that the Execute step took too long.

What could be causing the execute time to be so high for each frame, and how do I reduce it?

Comment: one option would be to reduce the views... how complex is the layout inside the CardViews?  do those views rely on dowloaded data or heavy calculations?

Comment: Not sure if it applies to GPU processing but Have you tried doing the processing on a separate thread? -- https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: @WilliMentzel the layout is a bit complex - I believe 2-4 layers deep across different cards. All the calculations, downloading data, etc. for each card is done in a parallel manner on separate threads, and the particular card is created and shown only when the required processing is finished

Comment: @Tasos the heavy lifting is done on separate threads. This is not due to any code running on the main thread, I am pretty sure of that.

Comment: @ManojMadanmohan make a separate project in which you build the exact same layout, without calculations without any logic behind it. see if it is equally slow. if yes, pls read this: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/index.html see if you can improve anything.

Comment: @WilliMentzel Is that the reason for high execute(red) times? All I could get,  is that high execute times are caused by complex custom views, or due to views being redrawn over and over again. I am not using any custom views. Is there a chance that views are being redrawn?

Comment: @ManojMadanmohan since i don't know your code, there is. the best thing is, like i described, to reproduce the problem with a minimal sample app.

Comment: Connect one of the lower end devices you are having an issue with. In AS click on (Android Monitor) and then (Monitor). There you can check CPU and GPU usage for your App to get a Graphical idea of whats going on

Comment: What is the meaning of red bars? How can they be reduced? That is the question. https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/inspect-gpu-rendering says nothing about it. It says about 2d renderer. But what is it? And how I can improve it?